# Can't change SSL bindings

Tags: iis-6

I can't change SSL bindings for a web site on IIS6. All buttons are disabled. I need to put there specific IP instead of "All unassigned".

Here is the screenshot (sorry it's in russian")
http://d.pr/6lA3

Comment: Are you logged in as an Administrator

Answer (score 1):

You must first add the certificate through the Directory Security -> Server Certificate section.  Once you have the certificate setup then the buttons won't be grayed out anymore.